# replace symbol .= php

Tags: php, xenforo

hello i have this code:

```
  $thread_qry5= "SELECT * FROM xenProve_prove ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 5";

                                    $row5 = XenForo_Application::get('db')->fetchAll($thread_qry5);

                                    foreach ( $row5 AS $rows5 ) {
                                        $viewid = $rows5['thread_id'];
                                        $viewtitle = $rows5['title'];
                                        $viewuser = $rows5['username'];

                                          $MostView .= 'div style="height:30px; width:640px; border-bottom:1px solid #999;padding:5px;">
                                                  <div style="height:40px; width:500px;float:left">
                                                      <div style="height:20px; width:650px; font-size:16px;color:#6d3f03;">'.$viewtitle.'</div>
                                                      <div style="height:20px; width:650px; font-size:12px;color:#6d3f03;">'.$viewuser.'</div>
                                                  </div>
                                          </div>';
```

how can replace this symbol .= ?
Xenforo system don't read this symbol (.=) 
I tried :

```
 $MostView = 'div style="height:30px; width:640px; border-bottom:1px solid #999;padding:5px;">
                                                  <div style="height:40px; width:500px;float:left">
                                                      <div style="height:20px; width:650px; font-size:16px;color:#6d3f03;">'.$viewtitle.'</div>
                                                      <div style="height:20px; width:650px; font-size:12px;color:#6d3f03;">'.$viewuser.'</div>
                                                  </div>
                                          </div>' . $MostView;
```

but don't work. 
And i tried the For cycle anche the While cycle but don't work.
Thanks you

Comment: Do you really need to concat or just to echo 5 times this string ?

Comment: $MostView = $MostView . div style="height:30px; width:640px; ...

Comment: What error do you get? That PHP code looks ok, maybe you'll need to define the variable BEFORE the `foreach` loop : `$MostView = '';`

Comment: Do you really need to concat or just to echo 5 times this string ?

Comment: 5 times of variable $MostView varying each time the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a string to another string (by a [concatenating assignment operator](https://www.php.net/language.operators.string)) that doesn't exist (yet). You have to define the string first:

```
$MostView = '';
```

and then:

```
foreach ( $row5 AS $rows5 ) {

    $viewid = $rows5['thread_id'];
    $viewtitle = $rows5['title'];
    $viewuser = $rows5['username'];

    $MostView .= 'div style="height:30px; width:640px; border-bottom:1px solid #999;padding:5px;">
                                              <div style="height:40px; width:500px;float:left">
                                                  <div style="height:20px; width:650px; font-size:16px;color:#6d3f03;">'.$viewtitle.'</div>
                                                  <div style="height:20px; width:650px; font-size:12px;color:#6d3f03;">'.$viewuser.'</div>
                                              </div>
                                      </div>';
```

I don't think this problem is related to XenForo. If you turn on error reporting (just check Google or Stack Overflow) you will get more usefull information about this error.

Comment: no it does not work. I'm trying to make a loop for 5 times the same item only changing the data each time for 5 times. But put this into a variable ($ MostView) that will later be recalled. If I write the code. = Works but being a function code with class and I think that gives him problems.